# Different kind of deserializing XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to deserialize XML from AdWords API to a list of models.  This is the XML format:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<report>
  <report-name name='GeoPerformance Report for 5/26/2014 12:00:00 AM'/>
  <date-range date='May 26, 2014'/>
  <table>
    <columns>
      <column name='clicks' display='Clicks'/>
      <column name='countryTerritory' display='Country/Territory'/>
      <column name='day' display='Day'/>
    </columns>
    <row clicks='24286' countryTerritory='United States' day='2014-05-26'/>
    <row clicks='26' countryTerritory='Africa' day='2014-05-26'/>
    <row clicks='286' countryTerritory='Europe' day='2014-05-26'/>
    <row clicks='242' countryTerritory='Asia' day='2014-05-26'/>
  </table>
</report>
```

My model class is this:

```
[XmlRoot("report")]
public class AdWordsGeoPerformance
{
    public int Clicks { get; set; }
    public string CountryTerritory { get; set; }
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }
}
```

I would like each row's attributes (clicks, countryTerritory, day) to map to an instance of AdWordsGeoPerformance.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tend to favor Linq to XML over deserialization.  You would have to play some games with many objects to be able to serialize/deserialize that data.  Just using XDocument is a lot easier for me.

This might be helpful in you are looking for an alternate way:

```
var adWords = new List<AdWordsGeoPerformance>();

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(doc);
foreach(var r in xDoc.Descendants("row"))
{
    var adWord = new AdWordsGeoPerformance()
    {
        Clicks = int.Parse((string)r.Attribute("clicks")),
        CountryTerritory = (string)r.Attribute("countryTerritory"),
        Day = DateTime.Parse((string)r.Attribute("day")),
    };

    adWords.Add(adWord);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to generate the classes with the xsd tool:

```
xsd your.xsd /classes
```

In a fast search, I found this: 
https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/reportdownload/v201109/reportDefinition.xsd

I'm not sure if that's the correct schema, if not find it (it should be stated in the documentation) and use it to generate your classes.